# a website that loads a lot of objects - remote proxy?

Tags: angularjs, html, design-patterns, highcharts, proxy

I have a website built using html5, bootstrap and angular.
When loading it, the user is asked to fill in a lot of search information and when pressing "go", I get a lot of data from my DB, and for each "operation" asked by the used, I create a table and a chart using high-charts.

The problem is that when the user asks for a lot of "operations" to show, it takes about 30sec+ to load the data and make it possible for the user to perform any action (including rolling down).

Is there any way to improve this?

one way I thought of was using proxy design pattern to make some of the charts and tables virtual until the moment when the user rolls down to see them, JS and high-charts.

It is important to say that when checking the networking using chrome debugger, almost half of the loading time was on the client side - I have to assume that this much time is consumed for building the charts. (of course the other half is on the server-side and I will have to handle it there)

thank you very much, even directions of search will be helpful

EDIT: It seems now that I am facing another problem of this sort.
I also have to deal with the same problem thats resolving from very long download time from the server. like I said before, I have a lot of data that needs to be calculated on the server side and then needs to be sent back to the client side. so again, what if I don't want to download the whole lot of it immediately but chunks by chunks? is it possible?
the server-side is written in C# MVC and entity framework

Comment: Can you please add the relevant client side code to your question? We can check it for any obvious issues.

Comment: unfortunately its restricted so i cant show any of the code. thats why im trying to figure out ideas to look at and general directions

Comment: RE your edit: Can you shift the order in which you loss your data depending upon what is in the dom - you could handle the same events that infinity.js uses and use these to trigger chunk downloads of the appropriate data, or perhaps the data that will be needed at the next scroll down. Basically use these events to load data as you go,  slightly in advance of when you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use something like [infinity.js](http://airbnb.io/infinity/). To render only the elements currently in view on the page, and respond appropriately to scroll events. Here is an excerpt from the API documentation, describing an element called `ListView`, which sounds relevant to your problem:

> A ListView is a container that moves content in and out of the DOM on
>   the scroll event. ListViews help keep repaint times of expensive pages
>   down (and scrolling smooth) by making sure that there are never too
>   many elements onscreen at a single time. ListViews excel at speeding
>   up long lists of complex HTML elements, where new content is
>   frequently appended to the end and existing content is rarely removed.

Comment: this listView works only once i have loaded all of my data to the client-side?
if i got it right, it speeds up the "viewing" of dom elements right?